# Is PWR plane acceptable as return path for high speed signals instead of GND?

Tags: signal-integrity

For high speed signals where ωL>>R for the transmission line, the return current becomes concentrated close to the wave guide which is the PCB track. The return path for this current shall be in the GND. My question is, what is the significance of using PWR as return path instead of GND? Is this possible? What will happen with high speed signal in this case?

The PWR plane in this case will be connected to PWR of the transmitter and receiver ICs.

Comment: It is surely possible as any plane can be used and it is possible to design in a change for reference plane. Whether acceptable in your case, too little details. What kind of signals or transmit/receive ICs you are talking about?

Comment: Yes but make sure the return current will have a continuous path, too. If the copper has a gap, stitch the path with a capacitor.

Comment: I am talking about routing an FPGA with DDR3 RAM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use a PWR plane as the reference for a high speed line.

The important thing is to make sure it's decoupled, that is shorted at AC by a small capacitor, to the reference terminal of any other port on that line **at the point** where the return current needs to flow to the port reference, usually GND.

If the line is going between ICs for instance, then that happens more or less automatically if each IC has its PWR plane decoupled to the GND plane close to the IC.

(edit)
In your question you state

> The PWR plane in this case will be connected to PWR of the transmitter and receiver ICs.

Yes, of course it will. The DC current to the device will flow through that route. But that's not where the AC component of the return signal current flows. The return signal current has to flow to the 'return signal current pin' of the device, which is almost always the ground pin of the device, or in devices that have multiple ground pins, the pin that's physically closest to the signal pin. Many high frequency ICs have a pair of ground pins, one either side of the signal pin, to be used for that purpose.

The signal return pin or pins should be connected to a local ground conductor that forms the 'impedance defining ground plane' (IDGP) of the signal trace. If later on, you want to switch that plane to the PWR plane, then you have to stitch the PWR plane to IDGP with one or more tiny ceramic capacitors to allow the return current to flow between the planes at their transition.

While excess length and so excess series inductance is just as important to avoid in this transition as it would be in a signal trace, the ability to use additional caps and paths in parallel comes to your aid when connecting this current. As ever, this is easier at lower frequencies.

Just as you need to avoid excess length and inductance, you also need to avoid excess width and capacitance. If the line runs for any length with both the former IDGP and the PWR plane in proximity to the line, perhaps one above and one below, the excess capacitance will lower the line impedance at that point, and cause a discontinuity.

The former two paragraphs are just saying emphasising that if good line impedance is required, then any junctions between different physical media have to be **designed**.

It may be possible to dispense with the notion of an IGDP altogether, and use capacitors from the adjacent signal return ground pins directly to the PWR plane, and configure the signal trace / PWR plane dimensions to give your required line impedance. If the signal is very high frequency, then you may have to design the physical sizes of these capacitors and their pads, perhaps treating them as elements of CPWG (CoPlanar WaveGuide), to get a good enough transition.

Summary - you can use **any** conductor on the board as a return conductor to define the impedance of a signal line. However, you need to design **all** of the transitions between source and sink of the signal path to have that design impedance. This is easier if that return conductor is the GND plane throughout.
(/edit)

Comment: So why is there such an obsession with using only GND as the reference plane for the high speed signals?

Comment: @quantum231 it depends who you ask. If you ask somebody who's obsessed, then you'll get an obsessive response. Using the GND plane is easy. Using the PWR plane requires a bit more thinking - getting decoupling caps in the right places. So if you don't want to go into the caveats, you just say 'GND plane', and leave it there.

Comment: There is a basic issue with using capacitors with high frequency signal. A real capacitor has ESL and ESR. Basically the capacitor reactance falls (as expected) until a certain point after which the ESL dominates and thus the reactance increases beyond that point. The cross over point where the capacitance and ESL has same reactance is called the resonance point I believe. Thus, using capacitor in practical life is basically not very effective. We can try and use a small package to try to get as less ESL as possible but that is not the best solution.

Comment: Signal "returns" to GND. I do not understand how something other than a GND plane can be used as the return path. I am very confused now. How will one calculate the characteristic impedance of the PCB track in this case?

Comment: @quantum231 FYI, when applying AC steady state principles, "ground plane" is AC-equivalent to either one. That is, they're synonymous. It's not obsessive, it's just the general term. (In other words, a category error: "ground plane" meaning any well-bypassed supply which is equivalent to ground; VCC and GND planes per se are a strict subset of this category, not exclusive.)

Comment: @Neil_UK,May l know what will happen if l give 3.3V power plane as a reference to 1.8V signals

Comment: @newbie Yes, you can use a 3.3 V plane as the reference for a high speed line. The important thing is to make sure it's decoupled, that is shorted at AC by a small capacitor, to the reference terminal of any other port on that line at the point where the return current needs to flow to the port reference, in your case between 3.3 V and 1.8 V power planes.

Comment: @Neil_UK,Thank you. What l understood from your statement is ,l need to place a small cap ,it's one end is connected to 1.8V and other end to 3.3V.Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @newbie The small cap has to go between the planes AT THE POINT near to where the signal makes a transition from being referenced by one to being referenced by the other.  'Near to' is defined with respect to the risetime of the signal, aim for labmda/20 or less. So with 1 us signals, you can be much looser with dimensions than with 1 ns signals.